# ¿Por qué no puedo retornar un array de tipo String a un activity en Android Java?

Tags: java, android, array

Tengo un método booleano en una clase hecha en Java para Android, sin embargo, el retorno de la variable array que estoy utilizando marca error cada que la utilizo en el activity donde quiero que esté.

**Este es mi método: (La clase se llama Querys)**

```
public String[] getAlumnos(Context context, String usuario) {
    String[] alumnos = new String[50];
    return alumnos;
}
```

**Este es el código de mi activity donde estoy intentando sacar el valor de dicho método y asignarlo a un nuevo array:**

```
Querys q = new Querys();
    String[] alumnos = q.getAlumnos(this, usuario); // <--- Aquí es el problema
    q.getAlumnos(this, usuario); // <--- Pues si lo uso sin asignarle el valor que retorna a ninguna variable, hace todo el trabajo perfectamente bien.
```

Esto es lo único que he podido sacar como "error" si se le puede llamar así.

```
2020-08-21 22:27:53.970 9073-9073/com.example.apk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.apk, PID: 9073
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:453)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
    at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:856)
    at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:606)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:428)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6753)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:720)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23196)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2802)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1647)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1930)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1535)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7405)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1044)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:839)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:774)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1030)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error no tiene que ver con Android sino que es un mal entendido con los arreglos.

`String[] alumnos = new String[50];`  ese código crea un arreglo de tipo `String` de 50 posiciones pero cada posición es `null`.

Antes de intentar acceder a un objeto en una posición del arreglo este debe haberse puesto ahí por ejemplo:

```
alumnos[0] = "alumno 0";
alumnos[0] = alumnos[0].toLowerCase(); // ya no hay error
```